# Can't get responses for intents in dialogflow using custom payloads

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm starting to use dialogflow in the google web interface, when I create intents from a text response it does works well, but if I try with the custom paylods I do not get a response.

E.G:

for the itent: "docker  Get logs"

I have set as response:

```
{
  "richContent": [
    {
      "title": "test",
      "type": "description"
    }
  ]
}
```

But as response I get: "Not available"

[image]

Comment: For what platform are you trying to write a custom payload? This is missing from your payload. If you look at the docs you will see that custom payloads are meant for platform specific responses that aren't supported by Dialogflow out of the box. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-rich-messages#custom

Comment: @Jordi I'm trying it for telegram